# how can i use django-tokenapi authentication through jquery ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, python-2.7, curl

i'm trying to get response through curl command it's working fine.
curl -d "username=root&password=rohit" http://task.woo.gy/api4/token/new.json

but if i'm trying to access through ajax it's not working here!! please check the below code..

```
function make_base_auth(user, password) {
            var tok = user + ':' + password;
            var hash = btoa(tok);
            return "Silly " + hash;
          }
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://task.woo.gy/api4/token/new.json",
    crossDomain: true,
    beforeSend: function (xhr){ 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', make_base_auth('root','rohit')); 
    },
    success: function (){
        alert("200"); 
    },
    failure: function(error){alert(error);},
    contentType:'application/json',
    dataType: 'application/json',
    processData: false,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, below code is working for me!!

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://task.woo.gy/api4/token/new.json",
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
       username: "root",
       password: "rohit"
    },
    success: function (data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```